# Do magic items that are horseshoes only work with creatures that have four hooves?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, equipment

[*Horseshoes of a Zephyr*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/horseshoes-of-a-zephyr) for example states:

> These iron horseshoes come in a set of four. While all four shoes are
> affixed to the **hooves of a horse or similar creature**, they allow the
> creature to move normally while floating 4 inches above the ground.
> This effect means the creature can cross or stand above nonsolid or
> unstable surfaces, such as water or lava. The creature leaves no
> tracks and ignores difficult terrain. In addition, the creature can
> move at normal speed for up to 12 hours a day without suffering
> exhaustion from a forced march.

The "similar creature" portion is rather vague. Is the item description saying that the creature needs four hooves, or that it needs to be a quadruped?

I am inclined to think it works with anything that is a quadruped, mainly for the purpose of the paladin spells *Find Steed* and *Find Greater Steed*.

Comment: I’ve corrected the magic item name, “Horseshoes of *a* Zephyr” is correct.

Answer (score 13):

##### It needs to be a quadruped with single toed hooves effectively identical to those of a horse. They're *horseshoes*, they're literally the size and shape of a horse's hoof, and have to be *nailed* into the hoof.

Being magical, I assume they can resize to a limited extent to fit any sized hoof, but they definitely won't work with arbitrary mounts from *Find Steed*/*Find Greater Steed*; if you try to nail horseshoes to a dire wolf, you're engaging in animal cruelty, and they'd presumably cripple your mount for life.

So basically, look at the mount and see: Does it have a horse-like hoof? For *Find Steed*, that would logically include just an actual horse or a pony. For *Find Greater Steed*, that would cover a pegasus and nothing else. Outside those spells, if you decide to ride a donkey, Sancho Panza-style, or a mule, or tame a zebra (I'm told that's impossible), lasso a unicorn (harder than the zebra?), etc., have fun, that should work just fine, they're all [equines (or magical equivalents)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidae) and the shoe should fit with a little magical aid in resizing (the same aid that allows you to assume that a 100 lb. elf can wear plate armor taken off the corpse of a 250 lb. orc chieftain; in practice, in the real world, two different 200 lb. human knights of the same height still needed individually custom fit plate armor). If you have a centaur buddy, the back half is a horse, so that should work too.

If your character gets a Sleipnir-like mount with horse hooves, but eight legs instead of four, RAW it should work, though a DM who demanded two sets for such an animal may have logic on their side, depending on the effects produced.

This is not to say there couldn't be *equivalent* magic items for less common mounts (e.g. *Doggie Booties of a Zephyr* for your mastiff or dire wolf mount), and perhaps a DM could exhibit a very giving sort of discretion and rule that magic "horseshoes" work on basically any 4+ hooved creature, with the magic enabling major reshaping and providing non-real world means of affixing the shoe, so "horseshoes" become "shoes appropriate to any mount" when they come near an otherwise incompatible animal's feet, but without that level of permissiveness, no, you can't put *horseshoes* on something that doesn't have the *feet* of a *horse*.

Comment: what about creatures with two hooves, such as Satyrs?

Comment: @PixelMaster "While **all four shoes are affixed to the hooves** of a horse or similar creature" — you will have to double stack them :)

Comment: Just to clarify - are you saying they won't work on e.g. elk (an option for Find Steed), giant goat or ox because they have split hooves? (IRL ox shoes exist but have a slightly different construction)

Comment: "They're horseshoes, they're literally the size and shape of a horse's hoof," Many magic items will change size to fit their users. "and have to be nailed into the hoof." Do they? They just say "affixed", not "nailed". You could glue them onto a cow's hooves, for instance - and maybe they just magically adhere without even needing that much.

Comment: @SilentAxe: I'm saying working on anything but single-toed ungulate (equine, or magical equivalent) hooves would require DM house rules. Horseshoes are for horse hooves (attaching to a single unbroken semicircle of hoof). Claiming they work on something with more than one toe, or a less thick hoof is like insisting a bat can wear gloves made for humans because they both have "hands", ignoring the massive structural differences between the two.

Comment: @nick012000: "Many magic items will change size to fit their users." As I said, this would be like assuming gloves for humans will fit a bat because we both have hands. If the DM wants to make a call for that extreme a resizing/reshaping, go ahead, but it's inventing abilities.

Comment: @nick012000: "They just say "affixed", not "nailed". You could glue them onto a cow's hooves, for instance - and maybe they just magically adhere without even needing that much." Cow's hooves don't match the shape; I could glue a horseshoe to your feet, but I doubt you'd move very fast. :-) In any event, actual "horseshoes" in the real world are always nailed (until the invention of modern acrylic glues, and even then, usually nails); there's an ancient "hipposandal" bound around the lower leg, but that's distinct from a horseshoe. "Affixed" meaning anything but "nailed" would be DM invention.

Comment: um *excuse* me, Don Quixote rode a broken down old plowhorse named Rocinante.  *Sancho Panza* rode a donkey.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: /me falls on my sword. (I literally read a large part of it, in translation, three months ago, and I'm ashamed I forgot)

Comment: @ShadowRanger It's fine, it's fine, I was being silly about it in the first place.

Comment: @ShadowRanger They're magic, they can adjust to fit the feet of the animal they're affixed to- and its entirely possible they don't need nails or glue at all, but just magically cling to the animal's foot like a magnet.

Comment: @nick012000: It's arguable whether the rules for non-matching body parts would allow "adjusting" of that sort (a reshape to a cow hoof seems possible, though cow hooves are fundamentally unsuited to being nailed to a horseshoe); I think it's iffy, but it's a reasonable DM judgement call w/o inventing rules. But saying "these are horseshoes, but they don't attach using *literally* the only mechanism horseshoes of a comparable historical period used" isn't just resizing or reshaping, it's disregarding the fact that they're *horseshoes*. If it was "footgear of a zephyr", sure. But they're not.

Comment: And note, even if you allow adjusting from one hoofed animal to another, I'm going to get mad at anyone who tries to shoe a creature that doesn't even have hooves. A cow hoof may be, to the ignorant, basically similar to horse hoof (they're not, anymore than a human foot and a dog's paw can both use sneakers but I can see where you'd think it). A wolf's paw is no more compatible with a horseshoe than boots are compatible with a snake tail (the example given for when non-humanoid can't use a given item).

Answer (score 8):

### A "similar creature" is one with horse hooves in specific.

The rules on [Wearing and Wielding Items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems) (DMG p.140) have this to say:

> A magic item meant to be worn must be donned in the intended fashion: boots go on the feet, gloves on the hands, hats and helmets on the head, and rings on the finger. [...] In most cases, a magic item that's meant to be worn can fit a creature regardless of size or build. Many magic garments are made to be easily adjustable, or they magically adjust themselves to the wearer.

However, it goes on to say:

> When a nonhumanoid tries to wear an item, use your discretion as to whether the item functions as intended. A ring placed on a tentacle might work, but a yuan-ti with a snakelike tail instead of legs can't wear boots.

So while magic items generally work for any creature with appropriate anatomy, what anatomy is "appropriate" depends on the DM to decide. Some DMs decide that boots work just fine on, say, lizardfolk, kobolds, and aaracokra "because magic", but many will say that these creatures lack the humanlike feet needed to wear shoes as we know them.

That said, the appropriate anatomy for horseshoes is horse hooves. They're shaped very specifically to match a horse's feet, not a deer's or tiger's. The text says "similar creatures" in order to cover the wide array of creatures that have horse hooves, but aren't listed as "horses" per-se, including ponies, pegasi, centaurs, and the back half of a hippogriff. (Hippogriffs, however, can't benefit from most magical horseshoes, since they can't wear the full set.)

These items would almost certainly not be appropriate for an ox, elk, boar, or other split-toed ungulate, and definitely wouldn't work for anything with paws, claws, or other non-hoofy feet. Unicorns are questionable -- while the art in the Monster Manual for 5th edition shows horselike hooves, traditionally, unicorns are often shown as having deerlike legs (and this is how they were depicted in 1st, 2nd, and 3rd edition D&D). Your DM will have to make a call on whether a unicorn is a swordhorse or a speardeer.

That said, you should feel free to work with the DM (or decide, if that's you) to create equivalent magic items for creatures who lack specific anatomy, such as anklets, greaves, or leg-wraps that grant the same benefits as magical boots or horseshoes, but function for creatures that have oddly shaped feet. If an elf-paladin's particular idiom involves riding elks and deer, that shouldn't stop them from accessing certain kinds of magic -- but they may not be able to just loot some *horseshoes of the zephyr* and use them. They may need to get a custom item made, or go to an elf city where *ivy leg wraps of the zephyr* might be more common.

Comment: I find any answer where a DM needs to know what a split-toed ungulate is to be iffy.

Comment: You don't, you just need to know if it has horse hooves or not.

Comment: "This does mean hippogriffs can't benefit from most magical horseshoes, since they can't wear the full set." Unless, as per the speculation on two hooved creatures in [the comment thread on my answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192202/do-magic-items-that-are-horseshoes-only-work-with-creatures-that-have-four-hoove/192203?noredirect=1#comment519338_192203), you could just nail two horseshoes in a stack to each of the hippogriff's valid hooves. :-) The commenter is wrong on satyrs (goat hooves aren't horse hooves), but the speculation works for a hippogriff, in theory.

Comment: I like that your answer comes to essentially the same conclusion [as mine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/192203/28941) with additional support from the 5E magic item rules for the plain English real world contention that horseshoes can only be attached to horse (or effectively horse) hooves. I knew there were rules on magic items that don't fit the expected body plan, but I didn't look up the precise wording, because *of course* you can't nail horseshoes to a hoof with a different shape or inadequately thickness, any more than a gorilla can wear sneakers "because it has feet". +1

Comment: @SeriousBri: Conveniently, the *only* single toed ungulates are equines (real world horse, donkey, zebra, and crossbreeds thereof), so everything else from the real world, and anything supernatural/unreal that isn't clearly borrowing hooves from a horse, would be ineligible. So yeah, as Darth Pseudonym says, the only question is "does it have horse(-like, aka equine) hooves?" (Amusing side-note: Evolutionarily and functionally, the next closest hoof to the horse is probably the rhinoceros's three-toed hoof; I heartily endorse trying to tame a rhino and put horseshoes on it [in the game only])

Comment: @ShadowRanger I mean I wouldn't allow you to affix two horseshoes to each hoof to qualify as 'wearing the set' anymore than you could put two boots on one foot to qualify as wearing a pair of magic boots.  They "must be donned in the intended fashion", which that clearly isn't.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: You're just biased against peg-legged pirates, you monster! ;-)

Comment: And one-handed greatsword experts, yes.

Answer (score 1):

### Nothing in the descriptions of the two horseshoe-type magic items published to date explicitly requires a creature with hooves *identical* to those of a horse.

The *DMG* offers the following on the subject of [wearing magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems) (p. 140; emphasis mine):

> A magic item meant to be worn must be donned in the intended fashion: boots go on the feet [...]
>
> **In most cases, a magic item that’s meant to be worn can fit a creature regardless of size or build.** Many magic garments are made to be easily adjustable, or they magically adjust themselves to the wearer.
>
> Rare exceptions exist. If the story suggests a good reason for an item to fit only creatures of a certain size or shape, you can rule that it doesn’t adjust. For example, armor made by the drow might fit elves only. Dwarves might make items usable only by dwarf-sized and dwarf-shaped characters.
>
> **When a nonhumanoid tries to wear an item, use your discretion as to whether the item functions as intended.** A ring placed on a tentacle might work, but a yuan-ti with a snakelike tail instead of legs has no way to wear magic boots.

There are two magic items presented as horseshoes in official D&D 5e publications so far: *[horseshoes of speed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/horseshoes-of-speed)* and *[horseshoes of a zephyr](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/horseshoes-of-a-zephyr)*. Both items use the same language in their descriptions:

> These iron horseshoes come in a set of four. While all four shoes are affixed to the hooves of a horse or similar creature . . . .

All we can derive from this language is that the creature must have hooves, and  that those hooves must be "similar" to a horse's. The word "similar" is otherwise undefined and entirely left to DM discretion. From the very fact that the word "similar" was included, however, we can deduce that the creature's hooves do not need to be *identical* to a horse's. Some degree of similarity less than identicality is sufficient.

Moreover, because we are talking about an explicitly magical object, there is little benefit to using real-world logic to reason about the *horseshoes*. Your mileage may vary, of course, but at least at the tables where I have played, the *DMG*'s discussion of size-changing magic items has meant, e.g., that magical plate armor looted from a long-limbed bugbear will reshape itself to fit a tiefling *with a tail*.

As for the *horseshoes*, granted, the "hooves of a horse or similar creature" requirement might be one of those "[r]are exceptions" mentioned in the *DMG*. Even so, there is nothing in their descriptions to suggest they could not be worn, say, upon the hooved toes of a hippopotamus. Nor do their descriptions specify how they must, or even *may*, be "affixed[.]" It *might* be with nails, but it would also be rules-correct to let them be glued on, or even *tied* on. And it is just as reasonable to permit the *horseshoes* to affix themselves magically without any need for nails or other fixatives. Nothing in their descriptions is to the contrary, and the *DMG* squarely commits the functioning of magic items worn by nonhumanoids to DM discretion. It is up to the DM to decide, based on the needs of the story, whether there is "good reason for [*horseshoes*] to fit only creatures of a certain size or shape[.]"

Answer (score 1):

### Any perissodactyloid with four true hooves will do

*Horseshoes of a Zephyr* states (emphases mine):

> These iron horseshoes come in a set of four. While **all four** shoes are
> affixed to the **hooves of a horse or similar creature**, they allow...

Grammatically, there are two ways to parse the 'or'; it *could* divide the second sentence into either comparing the:

"hooves of
(a horse) or
([a] similar creature)" - that is, affixed to the hooves of a horse *OR* affixed to the hooves of a similar creature.

or it *could* divide the

"(hooves of a horse) or
([a] similar creature)" - that is, they can be affixed to the hooves of a horse *OR* affixed to a similar creature which does not necessarily have hooves.

While both parsings are grammatically possible, in context we can see the second one does not make sense because the *hooves* of a horse are not themselves a *creature*; it is a false comparison.

Thus the first parsing is the only one possible in context, and this establishes two things for us:

1. The creature must have hooves and
2. It must be something similar to a horse

So, what does *similar to a horse* mean?

The DMG (p. 140) says in [Wearing and Wielding Items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-toed_ungulate) (emphases mine):

> A magic item meant to be worn must be donned **in the intended fashion**: boots go on the feet, gloves on the hands, hats and helmets on the head, and rings on the finger. [...] In most cases, a magic item that's meant to be worn can fit a creature **regardless of size or build**. Many magic garments are made to be easily adjustable, or **they magically adjust themselves** to the wearer.

This passage makes it clear that being similar to a horse **does not mean** being like a horse in size or build, since the horseshoes will magically adjust to that.  In what way then is a potential candidate similar to a horse?  It must have four hooves, as the magic item description implies.  And those hooves must be similar to horse hooves, not in size or build, but in...**shape.**

Putting these together, we see then the the horseshoes are appropriate for:

**Things that are like horses *in that they have hooves***, and also

**Have hooves that *are like horse hooves***, and also

**Have [at least] *four* hooves**.

So, we know that these **do not work** on the fantasy versions of goats, cows, pigs, sheep, and other equivalents to the real world [artiodactyls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-toed_ungulate).  While these may have hooves, their hooves are *not* like horse hooves in that they are not U-shaped like a horseshoe, rather they are half-u's ('cloven-hooved').  In particular, the magic item will not work on the *found steeds* of camels or elk.

Also, we know that they **do not work** on things that have horse-like hooves, but which have fewer than four of them.  While other comments and answers have suggested 'stacking' them, this runs afoul of the DMG injunction that magic items be worn 'in the intended fashion'.  Horseshoes are not meant to be worn doubled up.

However, we also know that **they will work** on things that have hooves like horses.  This includes obvious equines like *found steed* ponies and *found greater steed* pegasi.  But it also includes the fantasy equivalents of real-word [perissodactyls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd-toed_ungulate), such as tapir, whose hooves have the characteristic horse-like U-shape, even though they have many more than four of them.  In particular, the shoes will work on the *found greater steed* rhinoceros.