# Can a satyr benefit from magical horseshoes?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I have seen this question posed for centaurs with their four hooves, but what about a satyr with two? Both Horseshoes of Speed and Horseshoes of a Zephyr say:

> These iron horseshoes come in a set of four. While all four shoes are affixed to the hooves of a horse or similar creature [...]

Can a satyr just wear two of the horseshoes and benefit from their magic?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Do magic items that are horseshoes only work with creatures that have four hooves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/192202/23547)

Comment: @Atog Answers, as well as partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, and general advice to the asker, belong in answer posts and not in comments. You should post that as an answer, since it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Can a satyr wear just two of the horseshoes and benefit?

No, the shoes say (emphasis mine):

> While **all four shoes** are affixed to the hooves of a horse or similar creature

#### What if I 'stacked' them and the satyr wore two on each foot?

No, that is not the 'intended fashion' in which horseshoes are worn.  The DMG (p. 140) says in [Wearing and Wielding Items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems) (emphasis mine):

> A magic item meant to be worn must be donned **in the intended fashion**: boots go on the feet, gloves on the hands, hats and helmets on the head, and rings on the finger.

#### But there is natural variation in horseshoe thickness and magic items adjust in size to fit the wearer.  I bet I could double them up.

Maybe, but a satyr is not similar to a horse, and the shoes say (emphasis mine):

> While all four shoes are affixed to the hooves of **a horse or similar creature**...

For one thing, a satyr has just two legs.  For another, a satyr has toes and hooves like a goat - that is, two toes and two hooves per foot (cloven foot).  A horse has one toe and one hoof per foot.  Satyrs are not similar creatures to horses, and the magical horseshoes would not be the right *shape* for their feet, even if they magically resized.

Comment: The developer intent seems to be that horseshoes of speed are meant solely for mounts (5e had no published centaur race yet at the time the magic item was first published) to reduce their impact on combat. It's very similar to boots of speed with the exception of them being usable for only 10 minutes per long rest, somewhat mitgating their power in combat. Your DM might be more likely to compromise on it if you used the more limited rules for the boots instead of the horseshoes.

Comment: There is this [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/245786/88345) in worldbuilding.SE that covers precisely what you wrote in the last paragraph .

Comment: @Eddymage Yes, I remember reading that when I was working on my answer at the dupe question.  Once upon a time my father found in a field what he thought was an odd-shaped half-horseshoe, until he realized that it was an ox-shoe.

Answer (score 2):

#### No: all the four horseshoes must be worn.

A satyr has only 2 feet, as noted in the question and as it is clear from the image in the [Monster Manual](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17005-satyr).

The magic item's requirement is to [properly wear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems) all the four horseshoes for benefiting of its magical effect, hence wearing only two of them does not grant any effect.

#### Wait, horseshoes must be worn in the hooves: a satyr has 4 hooves!

As depicted in this wonderful [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/245783/would-a-satyr-wear-horseshoes/245786#245786) on worldbuilding.SE, indeed goats have 2 hooves per foot, and satyrs have two goat legs. Since horseshoes are meant to be fixed on a hoof, a particularly tailored reading of the rules about magic items that say that they (emphasis mine)

> [...] are made to be easily adjustable, or **they magically adjust themselves to the wearer**.

can be used for saying that the horseshoes of Speed/of a Zephyr will magically adapt to the feet of a satyr.

Nonetheless, as noted in Kirt's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208227/63061), this could be not sufficient, since the requirement is that the creature wearing these magic horseshoes must be a horse or a similar creature. A DM can anyway overrule this requirement and adopt the above interpretation of the rule about magic items.